# Статический вложенный класс (пример)

Tags: java, static

```
public class Outer {
    static class Nested{
        public void myMethod(){
            System.out.println("This is nested class");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer.Nested nested = new Outer.Nested();
        nested.myMethod();
    }
}
```

Почему во вложенном статическом классе мы создаём объект и только потом вызываем наш метод? 
Почему допустим не работает вот так: `Outer.Nested.myMethod();` - ведь статик же!

Answer (score 3):

Потому что метод `myMethod()` не статичный - для его вызова необходимо создать объект, у которого и будет вызываться метод.

Comment: Тогда в чём смысл делать класс static если мы всё равно создаём объект, а не работаем только с классом?

Comment: Тогда правильнее спросить, зачем делать класс внутри класса.

Чтобы создать экземпляр внутреннего нестатичного класса, необходимо иметь экземпляр внешнего класса. Если внутренний класс статичный - экземпляр внешнего класса не нужен, можно сразу работать с внутренним.